# Can I instantiate two RCTBridge instances?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

For some reason, when I try to instantiate an extra `RCTBridge` instance, only one gets launched (the one that was created first). Here's the code from my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Setup sync worker
  self.syncThreadBridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:[SyncWorkerBridgeDelegate new] launchOptions:nil];
  // React Native root view
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"Main_app"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  // Return
  return YES;
}
```

Using this code, only the sync thread bridge is started and the app's main bridge isn't launched (but the sync thread bridge successfully initializes and sends messages to Reactotron).

If I move sync thread bridge initialization below the main app bridge initialization, then the main app is initialized, presented to the user and the main app sends messages to Reactotron. However, the sync thread bridge then doesn't start and it doesn't connect to Reactotron.

I based my approach on the code from https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads — and the example code from there doesn't seem to work on the React Native 0.63 that I use.

So was the option to create multiple JS runtimes removed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just tried this on a brand new React Native 0.63.4 app, it works: https://github.com/backmeupplz/react-native-ios-threading-example

Comment: In fact, RCTBridge instances stop being created properly when I integrate Realm. Weird.

Comment: Added an issue in the Realm repo: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3522